# Not hitting the break point in visual studio - for startup external program

Tags: c#, visual-studio, autocad, class-library

I created a class library for third party application (Autocad) . I changed the start program path as shown in below[image]

While debugging, Autocad software got opened and all methods and functions are also executed without hitting the breakpoint. Is I need to change any settings, need your support.

Comment: Did you copy the PDB files? Does AutoCAD really load the DLL from your project's folder or is there a copy somewhere else? Have you tried attaching to a running AutoCAD process and then executing your functionality?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar after open the AutoCAD I load the DLL file and giving the command to AutoCAD. Not doing anything with the PDB file....

Comment: Well, to debug you most probably will need the PDB file, as it contains debugging information. Where's the DLL that's loaded by AutoCAD? Is the DLL loaded automatically or do you have to do something in AutoCAD? If it is not loaded automatically, start AutoCAD and attach the debugger to the process in VS.

Comment: DLL not loaded automatically..Once I starts debugging AutoCAD window will open then load DLL file by do something in AutoCAD. How to attach the debugger in VS?\

Comment: In Debug menu select "Attach to process" (or similar - using German VS, so I don't really know the English menu label). You need to make sure that the PDB file is there and maybe also that AutoCAD loads the DLL from your bin\debug folder. I'm not sure about the latter, however.

Comment: It automatically attach the AutoCAD to VS. PDB also there in bin/debug location.

Comment: Jeez... where does AutoCAD load the DLL from? bin\debug? Other folder? If other folder: is PDB there as well?

Comment: What about attaching your dll to autocad process.
To do this, open acad.exe manually and then from VS, select `Debug>Attach To Process..`and attach to autocad.exe process.

Comment: @HRM, I have the same problem (with different external program). When I use "Attach to Process" everything works fine and breakpoints work as expected, but when I use "Start External program", breakpoints doesn't hit and VS says it doesn't have debug information loaded. PS: I use Visual studio 2013

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the supported runtime version in acad.exe.config. In the `configuration` element, add these lines:

```
<startup>
  <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727" />
</startup>
```

Read [this post](http://through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/2010/04/hitting-breakpoints-in-net-class-libraries-while-debugging-with-visual-studio-2010.html) to get more information.